# How to make old layouts visible?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have a layout that is shown correctly, but after adding DrawerLayout my old layouts were hidden. Here is my code after adding drawer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <include
                android:id="@+id/activity_base"
                layout="@layout/activity_base"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2">
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/resturantlayout"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#bd4304">
                    <TextView
                        android:text="رستوران"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/txtresturant"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/imageButtonresturant" />
                    <ImageButton
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="150dp"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/resturantlogo"
                        android:id="@+id/imageButtonresturant"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        />
                </RelativeLayout>
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/coffeshoplayout"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:background="#d2ae6d">
                    <ImageButton
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="150dp"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/cofeelogo"
                        android:id="@+id/imageButtencofee"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:text="کافه ها"
                        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/textViewcofee"
                        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/imageButtencofee"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/servfoodlayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2">
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:background="#f58634">
                    <ImageButton
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="150dp"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/ghazalogo"
                        android:id="@+id/imageButtonghaza" />
                    <TextView
                        android:text="غذای آماده"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:id="@+id/textViewgghaza"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/imageButtonghaza"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
                </RelativeLayout>
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:background="#7db446">
                    <TextView
                        android:text="فست فود"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/textView3"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/imageButtonfastfood"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
                    <ImageButton
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="150dp"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/fastfoodlogo"
                        android:id="@+id/imageButtonfastfood"
                        />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/drawer_frame_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginLeft="56dp"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The ids of two old layouts are: "cofeeshoprow, servfoodlayout" that they were shown correct.

Comment: any body can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have used `android:layout_below="@+id/activity_base"` for the layouts which should be shown below the "activity_base". Generally in this cases try to match layouts using "android:layout_below".